# how-to get dimens (px format not dp) in px in java code?

Tags: android, android-layout

how can I read a dimen in java.

> <dimen name="something">10px</dimen>

**if I try**

> ```
> getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.something)
> ```

it returns 18 instead of 10. the result is bigger than expected, but if R.dimen.something is 540 px the result is 180. i don't understand this conversion. is there a way to get original value from dimen.

i need the values in px for drawing (non visible, inflated) views to canvas and saving the result as jpg. the result should always look the same and not depend on dpi.

> <integer name="something">10</integer>

is not an option, because it cannot be used in xml.

EDIT1:

i don't know why, but an other device returns the expected values. maybe it's a bug in the cyanogenmod version i'm using on my main device

EDIT2:

it was a bug, after updating my cyanogenmod version it work

Answer (score 2):

try one of these

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.something);
```

or

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.something);
```

Comment: with these functions i get the same result, with the difference that getDimension returns a float value

Comment: @Morcl174 Method returns float because it returns value in dp and we can set dp in floating values , and `getDimenstionPixelSize()` returns int because pixel values can not be in float.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the documentation of [Resources#getDimensions(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension(int)) it reads as follows

> `float getDimension (int id)` 
>  Retrieve a dimensional for a particular resource ID. Unit conversions are based on the current `DisplayMetrics` associated with the resources.

which means if your dimension definition looks like this 
`<dimen name="dimen_pix">10px</dimen>`

`getResources().getDimensions(R.dimen.dimen_pix)` would return 10.0

and if the dimension is specified as a dip 
`<dimen name="dimen_dip">10dp</dimen>`

`getResources().getDimensions(R.dimen.dimen_dip)` 
would return `10.0 x density` density here is your screen's relative pixel density with respect to a mdpi screen (160ppi)

If you are looking to get the exact defined value of a `dip` dimension you can use the following code snippet

```
float screenDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dipDimension = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.test_dimen);
float actualDimension = dipDimension/screenDensity; //required value
```

Comment: yes, i know, but i got 18 instead of 10 as result of 10px, but only on my main device, after update my cyanogenmod version it works as expected.